# Pickle EOFError saving lists

Tags: python, pickle, eoferror

I am trying to save multidimensional lists into a file, while keeping the structure of the lists. I figured using pickle would be the easiest:

```
for ... stuff:
    # stuff happens which creates the new list kWebsTemp that I want to save
    # now for every loop-run I want to append my file by adding the new list as an additional object

    with open('%s_%s' %(filename,Scent), 'wb') as file:
                        #file.write(kWebsTemp)
                        #file.write('\n')

                        pickle.dump(kWebsTemp, file)
```

If I now however try to load the lists, I am only able to load the first list that was saved.

```
with open('%s_%s' %('testData','E'), 'rb') as file:
        print pickle.load(file)
        print pickle.load(file)
```

So for the second print command I get the EOFError. Any idea whats going wrong here?

Comment: u need to dump only one object to the file, so the solution might be to construct a dictionary, and at the end just dump it using pickle, for nested objects using cPickle instead of pickle.

Answer (score 1):

'wb' has to be replaced for 'ab' in order to actually append the file for an object.