# I keep getting an EOF error in Python 2.7.9 when I try to unpickle a file

Tags: python

I was coding on Python, and I wanted to save some data using pickle, but I keep getting an EOF error,
and I can't find the problem. Here's the code:

```
# Imports
import cPickle as pickle
```

I skipped a bit of stuff here

```
with open("SAVE_FILE.pickle") as file:
    if file == None:
        pickle.dump(0, file)
    random_variable = pickle.load(file)
```

And this is my error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blablabla this is not important", line 172, in <module>
    random_variable = pickle.load(file)
EOFError
```

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

(random_variable is not the actual name of the variable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pickle EOFError saving lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391799/pickle-eoferror-saving-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Since you have kept the file handle opened, pickle will trying to load from the latest position of the file handle. You need to call `file.seek(0)` to reset the file handle position, so `pickle.load` will read from the beginning of the file handle.